# How do I load CSS & JS into Sails.js layout based on the route?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I have a Sails.js 0.11.0 application with a master `layout.ejs` file. Right now, I am using the standard asset pipeline and loading all my CSS & JS by dropping them in the `assets/styles` and `assets/js` folders.

The issue with this approach is that the application loads ALL the CSS & JS files relevant to the site regardless of whether the page that is being rendered needs it or not. I would like to be able to load specific CSS & JS files based on the page while leaving the common stuff to still get loaded through the asset pipeline. How do I go about doing that? I couldn't find any documentation to get this done.

Answer (score 2):

In production, everything should be getting minified so you won't be getting the multiple server hits that you are probably experiencing. Thus pull one style sheet and one js file.

If you really wanted to make this work though you could disable using the layout and include in each view the actual files you want to include, but you lose a few things with this approach.

-If you run through the Sails.js pipeline the files won't be auto added or removed when you add them to the js folder

-Minification will break your application so you would need to manually setup your own build process to properly handle or disable minification.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Adam! I actually wanted a hybrid approach. I know that Sails will minify my CSS and JS but I figured that might make the first request too heavy. Do you know if I can use this and still load selected resources only when I want it?

Comment: The thing I would try to do is to create a folder that isn't touched by the standard grunt tasks, and then just include those manually where they are needed.  You'd have to edit the build system to minifiy the files (or maybe you have them pre-minified) depending on your use cases.  I've sorta done things like this for custom fonts that only appear on one or two pages, as well as cdn hosted assets that i'm not hosting myself.

Answer (score 1):

Create a local folder **assets/js/local** to store any scripts that you might want to load separate to the pipeline.

Then in your **tasks/pipeline.js** file add the `'!js/local/*.js'` line to ignore any script files in the local folder.

```
var jsFilesToInject = [

  // Load sails.io before everything else
  'js/dependencies/sails.io.js',

  // Dependencies like jQuery, or Angular are brought in here
  'js/dependencies/jquery-3.3.1.min.js',
  'js/dependencies/popper.min.js',
  'js/dependencies/**/*.js',

  // All of the rest of your client-side js files
  // will be injected here in no particular order.
  'js/**/*.js',

  //Ignore local injected scripts
  '!js/local/*.js' 
];
```

In your **views/layout.ejs** template add a block under the SCRIPTS block...

```
<!--SCRIPTS-->
<script src="/js/dependencies/sails.io.js"></script>
<script src="/js/dependencies/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/dependencies/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/dependencies/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/scripts.js"></script>
<!--SCRIPTS END-->

<%- blocks.localScripts %>
```

In your page view template call your file/s...

```
<% block('localScripts', '<script src="/js/local/myLocalScript.js"></script>') %>
<div class="container">...</div>
```

Comment: The above answer is correct. Also note that to load local javascript files use `<%- blocks.localScripts %>` and to load loacl css files use `<%- blocks.localStyles %>`. I'll just leave it here in case somebody needs it.